# Your favorite sound effect in film. 

Tags: film-sound-design, scifi, sound-design, favorite

Hello!
What are you favorite sound effects in film?
1. best sci-fi effect
2. best organic effect.

Answer (score 2):

Lightsaber. T-Rex roar.

Answer (score 2):

I really liked the sun in Sunshine

Answer (score 1):

If I can digress for a second and mention that sound for the tendon cutting scene in 127 Hours. The use of guitar bending and screeching sent chills down spin. As far as organic effects go, the use of animal sounds in the Bat Plane.

Answer (score 1):

1. - Hypnotoad. All glory to The Hypnotoad!
2. - Creaks. Wood, metal or leather doesn't matter (um, well...in the project it does, of course), but plastic is often not as fun.

Answer (score 1):

1) I know it is overused now, but I LOVE the simple low frequency sine wave sweep in the low end or in the LFE channel.  It really makes me giddy every time I hear it.

2) A simple whoosh.  Baseball bat, pool cue, cloth, wire etc...  Great stuff.

(I wasn't aware of the Hypnotoad until today, it is pretty awesome!)

Answer (score 1):

This will probably be the most bland of answers but I've always loved the sound of the soda cup that Woody runs around in while he and buzz sneak into the pizza shack in Toy Story.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=6hCYihlt1Lk#t=2032s

Comment: I second the cup sound. Brings me back to my childhood no doubt. Great answer.

Answer (score 1):

+1 for lightsaber (prior the 1976 this sound just did not exist and now everyone knows it). The flap of bird wings (the effect is never the same once you know how it is created, but you you can feel smug that most people don't know).

Answer (score 1):

1. Silence in 2001
2. The wallpaper peeling off in Barton Fink

Answer (score 1):

One thing I also think is worth mentioning is that sometimes when you react to a sound that you like in  film it is not only the quality of the sound but the sound edit as well.  For example...the cup sound from Toy Story mentioned above...it is a great, clean, and "true" sound, but I think what is so striking and playful about it, is the edit and how it perfectly compliments the motion.

With that said...

1. +1 Light saber (so easy to mention, but it is so iconic) and the vocal effects for the Alien from Alien and Aliens
2. +1 for Creaks...I just love a good leather squeeze...a bad guy wearing black military gloves and making a fist...so good

Answer (score 1):

As I do love the sound of a light saber I think my favorite sound from starwars is the tie fighter. Which I believe is a raw sound of a jaguar hissing?

My favorite organic sounds are hard switches, kill switches, old buttons, I love vintage gear for that reason. If it makes a big CLUNK when you flip the switch for something, it's probably bad ass.

Answer (score 1):

Silence in Wild Strawberries- Ingmar Bergman and 
the Laser Gun in Wall. E

Answer (score 1):

The Sound of Optimus Prime's Gun from Transformers the Movie (the proper one). (40 seconds) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fB0_vJUc3o4

The other one is the sound of the train in opening sequence in on Once Upon A Time in the West

Answer (score 0):

-almost every creature from Lord of the Rings. (notably Balrog's and Orcs)

-seismic charges from Star Wars Episode 2